# How to read csv with double strings inside

Tags: r

Good evening,

I want to read a csv file which is seperated with, but also include some , in strings. This would be easy to solve, but my csv is really strange, because there are double "" and even triple """ in lines which have a , inside the string. No idea who does it like that but I have to handle it.

Here an example of how my csv looks like:

```
StationID,Longitude,Latitude,Height,Remark
0000002,26.074412,44.446770,0,Bucuresti
0000003,1.811446,50.901549,0,Calais
0000004,1.075329,51.284212,0,Canterbury
0000005,-3.543547,50.729172,0,Exeter
"0000007,9.733756,46.922368,744,""Fideris, Bahnhof"""
0000008,8.571251,50.051219,0,Frankfurt Flughafen
0000009,18.643803,54.355520,0,Gdansk
0000011,7.389462,47.191804,467,Grenchen
```

As you see, StationID 0000007 makes it difficult.

The only thing i've been able to do is like that:

```
StationID Longitude Latitude Height              Remark
1                                           0000002 26.074412 44.44677      0           Bucuresti
2                                           0000003  1.811446 50.90155      0              Calais
3                                           0000004  1.075329 51.28421      0          Canterbury
4                                           0000005 -3.543547 50.72917      0              Exeter
5 0000007,9.733756,46.922368,744,"Fideris, Bahnhof"        NA       NA     NA                    
6                                           0000008  8.571251 50.05122      0 Frankfurt Flughafen
7                                           0000009 18.643803 54.35552      0              Gdansk
8                                           0000011  7.389462 47.19180    467            Grenchen
```

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: What functions specifically did you try to use to read the file? `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv()` or `data.table::fread()`? And what exactly should these records look like after they've been read in?

Comment: The answer from G. Grothdieck above is perfect for me. I used read.csv. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the example data it seems sufficient to remove any double quotes that appear at both the beginning and at the end of lines and replace strings of consecutive double quotes with one double quote.

```
L <- readLines("myfile.txt")
read.csv(text = gsub('"+', '"', sub('^"(.*)"$', '\\1', L)), 
   colClasses = c(StationID = "character", Remark = "character"))
```

giving:

```
  StationID Longitude Latitude Height              Remark
1   0000002 26.074412 44.44677      0           Bucuresti
2   0000003  1.811446 50.90155      0              Calais
3   0000004  1.075329 51.28421      0          Canterbury
4   0000005 -3.543547 50.72917      0              Exeter
5   0000007  9.733756 46.92237    744    Fideris, Bahnhof
6   0000008  8.571251 50.05122      0 Frankfurt Flughafen
7   0000009 18.643803 54.35552      0              Gdansk
8   0000011  7.389462 47.19180    467            Grenchen
```